# Oracle: Quick way to list all database links

Tags: oracle, database-link

The title says it all, is there a way to quickly list all the current database links in oracle?

Something along the same lines as this, which lists the current user's tables:

`select * from user_tables;`

Thanks,
GC.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

These views are helpful for working with DB links in Oracle:

- DBA_DB_LINKS  - All DB links defined in the database
- ALL_DB_LINKS  - All DB links the current user has access to
- USER_DB_LINKS - All DB links owned by current user

See more in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1039.htm#REFRN20050)

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT DB_LINK, USERNAME, HOST FROM ALL_DB_LINKS
```

you can try that, perhaps it can help you solve your problem

Comment: Doesn't this return only the links available to the current user?  Just for clarification...